# In the marvel movies what order did S.H.I.E.L.D/Nick Fury appear to the main movie character

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

Which movie did S.H.I.E.L.D and/or Nick Fury first appear in and what order subsequently did the former appear in other Marvel comic book movie adaptions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are talking about Samuel L Jackson or S.H.I.E.L.D. then it would be:

1. Iron Man
2. Incredible Hulk
3. Iron Man 2
4. Thor (Samuel L Jackson does appear in the credits, but other S.H.I.E.L.D. operatives appear in the movie)
5. Captain America:The First Avenger

This should be it I think, its pretty much all the recent films released by marvel.

Answer (score 4):

I remember seeing him first in [Iron Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_%28film%29) followed by the [Incredible Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_%28film%29) and lastly on [Captain America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%3a_The_First_Avenger). I don't remember watching him on Thor I didn't watch the credits on Thor because he comes in Iron man after the credits.

PS: I am assuming you're talking about Samuel Jackson as Nick Fury in the recent movies.

Edit: Forgot to add [Iron Man 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_man_2) despite the fact I watched the movie on first day. It turns out there is a post credits scene in [Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_%28film%29) like in the Iron man movie and SLJ does make an appearance there too.

Comment: yep SLJ. Not just the character though, SHIELD as well, cause only SHIELD was in Thor.

Comment: KFury WAS NOT IN TYE INCREDIBLE HULK tony stark was